# Как обрабатывать данные без моего jupyter kernel?

Tags: python, оптимизация, pandas, машинное-обучение, jupyter-notebook

Я хочу обработать данные в [unupervised.py notebook](https://github.com/aswalin/SQuAD/blob/master/unsupervised.ipynb). Однако каждый раз, когда я запускаю его, кажется, что ядро умирает.

В частности, это когда я выполняю эту строку:

```
train['sent_emb'] = train['sentences'].apply(
    lambda x: [dict_emb[item][0] if item in
    dict_emb else np.zeros(4096) for item in x])
```

Зная, что

```
 >>> train.shape
 (130318, 4)
 >>> len (dict_emb)
 179862
```

Я не знаю, можно ли уменьшить требуемые ресурсы. Может быть, это проблема памяти? Существуют ли онлайн-решения? На данный момент я собираюсь попробовать Google Collaboratory ...

Вот пример ввода.

```
    answer_start    context     question    text
0   269     Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ b...   When did Beyonce start becoming popular?    in the late 1990s
1   207     Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ b...   What areas did Beyonce compete in when she was...   singing and dancing
2   526     Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ b...   When did Beyonce leave Destiny's Child and bec...   2003
```

ожидаемый результат :

```
    answer_start    context     question    text    sentences   target  sent_emb    quest_emb
0   269     Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ b...   When did Beyonce start becoming popular?    in the late 1990s   [Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ ...   1   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...   [[0.00852411, 0.017743437, 0.029916534, 0.0259...
1   207     Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ b...   What areas did Beyonce compete in when she was...   singing and dancing     [Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ ...   1   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...   [[0.022155158, 0.035662126, 0.029916534, 0.025...
2   526     Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ b...   When did Beyonce leave Destiny's Child and bec...   2003    [Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ ...   3   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...   [[0.016932432, 0.018768348, 0.029916534, 0.025...
```

Я думаю, что это проблема памяти.

#### диагностика

```
>>> train.memory_usage (index = True, deep = True)
Index                  80
answer_start      1042552
context         130824648
question         15084292
text             10207009
dtype: int64
```

#### идея

На данный момент идея выйти из нее - либо сделать это с помощью colab.research.google.com, либо использовать [swap](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/).

Comment: Почему в строке кода у вас русское "если" и "в"?

Comment: @insolor плохой код и плохой отступ!

Comment: @Marine1, приведите небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных

Comment: @MaxU Да, конечно !

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)